# Typescript class raise event

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create a countdown js component in typescript and have the following.

I would like on each tick to raise an event with the remaining count down.

I am using vs 2017 if it matters.

```
export class DateCountDown {

   constructor(date: any) {

     this.startCountDown(date);

   }   

   startCountDown(date: any) {
       const thousand = 1000;
       const sixty = 60;
       const twentyfour = 24;

       setInterval(() => {
           const now = new Date().getTime();
           const t = date - now;

           const days = Math.floor(t / (thousand * sixty * sixty * twentyfour));
           const hours = Math.floor((t % (thousand * sixty * sixty * twentyfour)) / (thousand * sixty * sixty));
           const minutes = Math.floor((t % (thousand * sixty * sixty)) / (thousand * sixty));
           const seconds = Math.floor((t % (thousand * sixty)) / thousand);

         //Raise the event with above values
       }, 1000);
}
```

}

If raising multiple values in an event is not ideal, I created a class to store the value and then raise this.

```
export class CountDownValues {
    daysLeft: number;
    hoursLeft: number;
    minutesLeft: number;
    secondsLeft: number;
    constructor(days: number, hours: number, minutes: number, seconds: number) {
        this.daysLeft = days;
        this.hoursLeft = hours;
        this.minutesLeft = minutes;
        this.secondsLeft = seconds;
    }
    public get days(): number {
        return this.daysLeft;
    }
    public get hours(): number {
        return this.hoursLeft;
    }
    public get minutes(): number {
        return this.minutesLeft;
    }
    public get seconds(): number {
        return this.secondsLeft;
    }
}
```

I am simply trying to create a basic js lib/component that I give it a date and every second it raises an event with time remaining, from there I can assign the different values for days, hours, minutes and seconds to appropriate elements.

Comment: What is the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: I dont know how to raise the event from my class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If have understood your question you want to emit an event, there are many ways of doing this... You can use a 3rd party event emitter or create a basic on your own... You can also make something that resembles an event emitter something like this...

```
class CountDownValues {
  daysLeft: number;
  hoursLeft: number;
  minutesLeft: number;
  secondsLeft: number;
  constructor(days: number, hours: number, minutes: number, seconds: number) {
    this.daysLeft = days;
    this.hoursLeft = hours;
    this.minutesLeft = minutes;
    this.secondsLeft = seconds;
  }
  public get days(): number {
    return this.daysLeft;
  }
  public get hours(): number {
    return this.hoursLeft;
  }
  public get minutes(): number {
    return this.minutesLeft;
  }
  public get seconds(): number {
    return this.secondsLeft;
  }
}

class DateCountDown {
  onCountDown: (values: CountDownValues) => void;

  constructor(date: Date) {
    this.startCountDown(date);
    this.onCountDown = () => {};
  }

  startCountDown(date: Date) {
    const thousand = 1000;
    const sixty = 60;
    const twentyfour = 24;

    setInterval(() => {
      const now = new Date().getTime();
      const t = date.valueOf() - now;

      const days = Math.floor(t / (thousand * sixty * sixty * twentyfour));
      const hours = Math.floor((t % (thousand * sixty * sixty * twentyfour)) / (thousand * sixty * sixty));
      const minutes = Math.floor((t % (thousand * sixty * sixty)) / (thousand * sixty));
      const seconds = Math.floor((t % (thousand * sixty)) / thousand);

      if (this.onCountDown) {
        this.onCountDown(new CountDownValues(days, hours, minutes, seconds))
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}

let countDown = new DateCountDown(new Date());
countDown.onCountDown = values => console.log(values);
```

Here's a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-awx9gy?file=index.ts

> OP: Any reason why i would prefer a 3rd party over this?

1. You can only have one listener at a time, meaning `countDown.onCountDown = x => console.log("from first", x); countDown.onCountDown = x => console.log("from second", x);` won't work... You will only see "from second" as it overrides the first. It's not even an event emitter actually... It's kinda a callback in disguise... `countDown.on("countDown", x => console.log(x))` is an event emitter because it registers the listener instead of overriding...
2. People are usually more familiar with `foo.on("bar", x => console.log(x))` or  `foo.addEventListener("bar", x => console.log(x))`

Nevertheless there should be no problem in using this if you are making your own tiny thing which only you are working on or will be using... However to overcome 1st reason you could still implement something as simple as [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-3zps3u?file=index.ts)

Comment: thats exactly what i wanted, a class with event emitter, so that is perfect, thanks. Any reason why i would prefer a 3rd party over this?

Comment: @Zoinky You're welcome! :D I have answered your question in the post itself because it's a little long xD

Comment: very cool, say i want to do the .on("bar") what do i have to change in your second example? sorry for all the q's, havent done much js in terms of raising events and so on. I am adding a second event that is raised when timer is <= 0 https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ppehvs?file=index.ts

Comment: You can do something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-adfmda?file=index.ts)... This is quite type-safe but I would suggest using something like [this](https://github.com/bterlson/strict-event-emitter-types) library